# How did people calculate the zeros of the Bessel functions before the electronic computer?

Tags: mathematics

The Bessel function appears in many mathematics and physics problems. Their zeros are solutions of many problems. So how did people calculate them at 1900?

Did they have some good series?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but my guess is that it was done via the residue theorem or Rouché's theorem. I remember seeing pages and pages of  computations (forgot where) that Riemann did (by hand!) computing zeroes of the zeta-function.

Comment: See around p. 500 of the 1922 edition of Watson's book **A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions** --- [copy at University of Michigan Historical Math Collection](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=umhistmath;idno=ACV1415.0001.001) AND [copy at archive.org copy](https://archive.org/details/treatiseontheory00watsuoft). Also, a google-books search for [bessel function zeros calculation](https://www.google.com/search?q=bessel+function+zeros+calculation&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899) restricted to the 1800s gives several freely available references.